# Using list comprehension to remove undesired rows and columns and convert all string items into integer type

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a data-set of student's marks in a CSV format as follows:

```
data = '''student,maths,science,english,nepali,computer
John,57,77,73,50,55
Mark,52,66,89,78,50
Ben,57,85,53,87,53
Toby,90,63,64,76,58
Anna,52,97,88,81,51'''
```

I want it to convert it into a nested `list` using the following process:

1. Remove the first row, as well as the student's names, which are the first elements of each subsequent row
2. Convert all the remaining elements, representing marks, into integers

I would like to do this with a `list` comprehension.

Desired output:

```
[[57, 77, 73, 50, 55],
 [52, 66, 89, 78, 50],
 [57, 85, 53, 87, 53],
 [90, 63, 64, 76, 58],
 [52, 97, 88, 81, 51]]
```

I have tried the following code (**works**, but without using list comprehension):

```
 def read_data(file_name):
'''function to read data from a file, process it and store 
it in a data matrix (2D list)
returns the data matrix'''

file = open(file_name,"r")
data = file.readlines()
file.close()

mat = []
for line in data:
    mat.append(line.replace("\n","").split(","))

for i in range(1,len(mat)):
    for j in range(1,len(mat[i])):
        mat[i][j] = int(mat[i][j])
return mat
```

Comment: it would be better if you added the sample input as code/text instead of a image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you have a for loop of the following form:

```
result = []
for object in iterable:
    result.append(function(object))
```

You can recast it as a `list` comprehension as follows:

```
result = [function(object) for object in iterable]
```

Accordingly, here we can have the following:

```
mat = [line.replace('\n', '').split(',') for line in data]
```

However, note that we have a `split` call for each value of `line`, which means we have a nested `list`, and we want to convert each element of the *inner* `list` to an integer. For a nested `list`, we need a nested `list` comprehension. Going back to the above pattern, it is clear that the function is `int`:

```
mat = [[int(element) for element in line.replace('\n', '').split(',)] for line in data]
```

Unfortunately, this *still* will not work because *the first line of `data` is the headings and the first element of each line is the students' names*. Therefore, we need to separate our data into headings, names and marks:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')

processed_data = [line.replace('\n', '').split(',') for line in data]

headings = processed_data[0]
names = [line[0] for line in processed_data[1:]]
marks = [[int(element) for element in line[1:]] for line in processed_data[1:]]
```

Comment: Good to see a well explained answer. +1

Comment: yes well explained than my answer, upvote from me too

Answer (score 3):

Here we go

```
data = """student,maths,science,english,nepali,computer
John,57,77,73,50,55
Mark,52,66,89,78,50
Ben,57,85,53,87,53
Toby,90,63,64,76,58
Anna,52,97,88,81,51"""

output = [[int(item) for item in line]
          for row in data.split("\n")[1:]
          for line in [row.split(",")[1:]]]

print(output)
```

Which yields

```
[
    [57, 77, 73, 50, 55],
    [52, 66, 89, 78, 50],
    [57, 85, 53, 87, 53],
    [90, 63, 64, 76, 58],
    [52, 97, 88, 81, 51]
]
```

This uses list slicing (`[1:]`) and the variable names are self-explanatory.

---

*Hint: For possible future questions it is always better to provide text which can then be copied and pasted - here you get help quicker.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `csv` module here.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

def read_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        next(reader)                   #Skip header
        result = [list(map(int,row[1:])) for row in reader]    #list comprehension
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, instead of your second loop:

```
mat = [list(map(int,i)) for i in mat]
```

Comment: I tried:  mat = [list(map(int,i[1:])) for i in mat[1:]]  instead!! Anyways it helped !! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("your_file.txt") as f:
    c = f.readlines()

o = [x.replace("\n","").split(",")[1:] for x in c[1:]]
```

This line is what would be of interest to you,

`[x.replace("\n","").split(",")[1:] for x in c[1:]]`

For every line x from the file, replace "\n" and split them into list by ",".
After splitting you can ignore the first index [0] which will be the name you wanted to drop.